# Tools to work with App Engine data dumps

Tags: database, google-app-engine, backup

Using [the bulkloader.py utility](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) you can download all data from your application's Datastore.

It is not obvious how the data is stored, however. From the looks of it, you get a SQLite file with all data in binary format in a single table:

```
sqlite> .tables
bulkloader_database_signature  result  

sqlite> .schema result
CREATE TABLE result (
  id BLOB primary key,
  value BLOB not null,
  sort_key BLOB);
```

Are there any tools to work with this data?

Comment: What did you want to do with the data, precisely?

Comment: @Nick: Read it, make reports from it. Data mining.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, no tools yet. Just to share what I have found so far:

The binary data stored in the column value is in Google Protocol Buffer format.
Every row represents one entity.

Using the Java SDK, you can decode the data:

```
 OnestoreEntity.EntityProto m = new OnestoreEntity.EntityProto();
 m.parseFrom(data);
 Entity entity = EntityTranslator.createFromPb(m);

 System.out.println(entity.getAppId());
 System.out.println(entity.getKind());
 System.out.println(entity.getKey());

 // the properties (a Map)
 System.out.println(entity.getProperties());
```